# how install all custom module in project using terminal in odoo 10

Tags: module, installation, odoo-10

I have a folder name champion which have custom module i want to all module install in odoo 10 when the serer is run in terminal.
expect install manually one by one please sort out my problem.

Comment: when start the server in terminal install all custom module in odoo 10 just like --update=all

Comment: i want all module intall in champion folder ~/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo-bin --addons-path="odoo-dev/custom_addons/champion/,odoo-dev/odoo/addons" -d champnew

Answer (score 0):

I not sure it's a good solution, but it will full fill your requirement. Try below steps.

1. Create new module called `bundle_pack`.
2. Add depends to all module available in custom champion folder.
3. Install `bundle_pack` via terminal it will install all other modules.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: i want all module intall in custom champion folder ~/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo-bin --addons-path="odoo-dev/custom_addons/champion/,odoo-dev/odo‌​o/addons" -d champnew

Comment: i want do not enter <custom module name> one by one i want folder name which have lot of custom module and all custom module install automatically

Comment: your answer is really help full please tell me list of custom module in champion folder depends of many other custom module in that folder we depends bundle_pack all custom module priority wise are not ?????

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand your last comment.

Comment: In 2nd step add depends  all module available in custom champion folder. my Point is my Champion folder list of custom module depends each other So when depends in bundle_pack all custom module is priority wise or random ????

Comment: i was asking if i have 5 modules a,b,c,d and e and a module depends upon b and c on a in this case though i have to prioritize each module in bundle_pack_all or randomly place them ?? or will you elaborate your answer with some demo if possible.

Comment: if module `a` depends `b` & `c`., you only need to add `a` as depends.